# Joomla Pagination Incorrect

Tags: joomla3.0

I am using Joomla 3 with a custom template, I am trying to edit the Pagination as when I click the second page an item is cut off.

The page has three columns, 6 items per page however one item is not shown at the start of the first page. When I go to the second page it is set to 'start=7' however it should be 'start=6'

How do I edit the calculated numbers in PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pagination being created in the core of joomla and I don't think that could be wrong.
You could change the result per page value at:

```
System -> Global Configuration -> Default List Limit
```

If you still have wrong result please check your css if may be a rule that hides items.

Hope this helps